# toolbar sortby price in custom phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, toolbar

I have created **a custom module**. The `custom.phtml` file lists all the products of a category and subcategory. I want to place toolbar with sort by price on the top of the category.

I have **included the toolbar using the following code in `custom.phtml`.**

```
$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($catid); // My parent category id is 15
$prodCollection = $category->getProductCollection()
                      ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'asc');  //gives me collection of products from parent as well as products of subcategory

$toolbar = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list')->getToolbarBlock();
$toolbar->setCollection($_productCollection);
$toolbar->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager');

echo $toolbar->toHtml();
```

List and grid view is working but **Sort by is not working in custom phmtl** Collection to pass to toolbar to work??.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `->addAttributeToSort('name', 'asc')`

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catid); 
$_productCollection = $category->getProductCollection(); // Without sorting by name

$pager = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->createBlock('page/html_pager');

$toolbar = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list')->getToolbarBlock();

$toolbar->setCollection($_productCollection);
$toolbar->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager);
echo $toolbar->toHtml();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer ** but it is not working in custom.phtml page  **   `$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($name, 'name');
$_productCollection = $category->getProductCollection();
$toolbar = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/product_list')->getToolbarBlock();
 
   $collection = $_productCollection;

   
  $toolbar->setCollection($_productCollection);
  
  $layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

  $pager = $layout->createBlock('page/html_pager');

 $toolbar->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager);
 
  echo $toolbar->toHtml();`